# How to properly create a whole shape from a TextLayout?

Tags: java, 2d, awt, shadow

How do I create a Shape that rensembles the whole Text/String rather than just the outline?
What I got currently from `Shape outline = textTl.getOutline(null);`

[image: example picture]

The problem is that I invoke the `drawShadowedShape(outline, g2d);` on the outline shape, so the shadow is drawn over the font. But I want to invoke the `drawShadowedShape(outline, g2d);` not on the outline but the Text-Shape as whole thing, so that the shadow is drawn around the Font not like in the example on the outline.

Prior to asking this question I read in the documentiaon about all `TextLayout` methods that return a Shape object, but I did not find the correct one by my self.
For this snippet to work you just need to supply a valid font here: `String fName = "fonts/SugarBomb.ttf";`

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GradientText extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 360;
    private static final int PREF_H = 200;
    
    private static Font font;
    private static final int COLOR_COUNT = 3;
    private static final Color BG = Color.ORANGE;
    private Paint myPaint;

    public GradientText() {
        String fName = "fonts/SugarBomb.ttf";
        InputStream is = FontTest.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            font = font.deriveFont(20.0f);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
        setBackground(BG);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        float[] fractions = new float[COLOR_COUNT];
        Color[] colors = new Color[COLOR_COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            fractions[i] = ((float)i) / COLOR_COUNT;
            
            if(i%2==0) {
                colors[i] = new Color(248, 57, 1);
            }else {
                colors[i] = Color.yellow;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(colors[i]);
            System.out.println(fractions[i]);
        }
        myPaint = new LinearGradientPaint(0, 0, PREF_W, 0, fractions, colors);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        String s = "Look ma, I'm Stroked";
        TextLayout textTl = new TextLayout(s, font, frc);
        
        Shape outline = textTl.getOutline(null);
        
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics(getFont());
        int x = (getWidth() - outline.getBounds().width) / 2;
        int y = ((getHeight() - outline.getBounds().height) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
        g2d.translate(x, y);
        
        Stroke stroke = g2d.getStroke();
        g2d.setPaint(myPaint);
        g2d.fill(outline);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.2f));
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawShadowedShape(outline, g2d);
        g2d.draw(outline);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GradientText mainPanel = new GradientText();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GradientText");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
    
    public static void drawShadowedShape(Shape shape, Graphics2D g2d) {
        Color holdColor = g2d.getColor();
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        AffineTransform holdTransform = g2d.getTransform();
        // want the shadow to be one line width pixel offset
        float lineWidth = g2d.getStroke() instanceof BasicStroke ? ((BasicStroke) (g2d.getStroke())).getLineWidth()
                : 2.0f;
        //System.err.println("DrawingUtilities.drawShadowedShape(): lineWidth = "+lineWidth);
        g2d.translate(lineWidth, lineWidth);
        g2d.draw(shape);
        g2d.setColor(holdColor);
        g2d.setTransform(holdTransform);
        g2d.draw(shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I suspect the answer would lie in drawing the shadow first, with both the outline and fill shifted and darkened as needed, before drawing the main text outline / texture over the top.

Comment: Ahhh thank you I will try to invoke the shadow draw call earlier